# How does Trello reload the board in real-time?

Tags: javascript, html, trello

I'm using [trello.com](http://trello.com) to manage my work boards (something like Kanban board of Scrum)
And I really want to know that, how Trello cans realtime reload my board when other person changing this board, what's technique they used?

It's mean that, when I open my board on two browsers. Changing something on the first browser, automatically, the second browser is reload, very fast, the change is showed!

Somebody can tell me, how they do that :D

Many thanks!

Comment: Trello uses web sockets for real time communication.

Answer (score 5):

According to [their blog](https://blog.trello.com/the-trello-tech-stack), they use a modified version of the [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) client and server libraries.

The underlying technology for this is [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), which allow for realtime TCP communication through the browser. If the browser being used doesn't support that API, it falls back on XHR/JSONP polling,